# qsort in struct, but the sorted struct is messy

Tags: arrays, c, string, struct, qsort

I want to sort an array of struct using qsort by their name, But the output is not what I expected.

```
typedef struct node{
    char name[64];
    char ingredient[10][64];
}node;

int compare(const void *a, const void *b){
    node *nodeA = (node *)a;
    node *nodeB = (node *)b;
    return strcmp(nodeA->name, nodeB->name);
}

int main(){
    int num; scanf("%d", &num);
    int sum[num];
    node recipe[num];
    //input
    for(int i = 0; i < num; i++){
        scanf("%s", recipe[i].name);
        scanf("%d", &sum[i]);
        for(int j = 0; j < sum[i]; j++){
            scanf("%s", recipe[i].ingredient[j]);
        }
    }
    //sort
    qsort(recipe, num, sizeof(node), compare);

    //print out to check
    printf("\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < num; i++){
        printf("%s ", recipe[i].name);
        for(int j = 0; j < sum[i]; j++){
            printf("%s ", recipe[i].ingredient[j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
```

input as follows

```
5
cake 4 egg flour sugar butter
omelet 4 egg bacon ham butter
bread 1 flour
breed 0
breag 0
```

output as follows

```
bread flour    
breag H??    
breed ?i?
          
cake 
omelet
```

expected output as follows

```
bread flour 
breag 
breed 
cake egg flour sugar butter 
omelet egg bacon ham butter
```

Moreover, what if I also want to sort the ingredient within each node as follows, how to achieve this?

```
//maybe I can do something like this
for(int i = 0; i < num; i++){
    qsort(recipe[i].ingredient, num, sizeof(recipe[i].ingredient[0]), mycompare//to compare each ingredient);
}
```

expected output as follows

```
bread flour 
breag 
breed 
cake butter egg flour sugar  
omelet bacon butter egg ham
```

Comment: `sum[]` is separate from the `node` structs... You need to put the count of ingredients _inside_ the struct so each instance retains its own count when sorted... That's all you need to fix (at a quick glance.)

Comment: Start by printing your array *before* sorting it.  Is it what you expect?  If not, then the problem has nothing to do with `qsort`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible and it is common to write code this way.

But:

- will cost you much more time than needed to write and specially to test
- is slower to change anything
- is harder to use in other scenarios

I will show down here a common way to write this --- and to reason about this --- using your code as input. I will write here as I code and at the end there will be a complete program, with output and comments along the way.

**I will use no memory allocation and will not change sorting algorithm. It is just a toy just to show a way to write this kind of code. A way that usually works at the first run, as it worked here.**

This can be a long post. No **TL;DR**

```
typedef struct node
{
   char name[64];
   char ingredient[10][64];
} node;
```

This is the basic data? No. And there is no need to name the `struct`: let it anonymous. And the name is already showing something: a `node`? A node is part of *something* and your program has no representation for this *something*.
As far as your model is from the real thing, more trouble you will have to operate on your data.

Want proof? Look at the array `sum` and the value `num` in your code. If you need to write this to a file, a simple thing, the data is spread inside the code. Imagine an array of recipes and how in the world would you control that?

Encapsulation is the way to go, as we see in all **OOP** languages. Encapsulation and OOP is much more a phylosophy than a technology, specially in `C`.

#### The data as a `thing`

This is the start of the posted code:

```
    int num;
    scanf("%d", &num);
    int  sum[num];
    node recipe[num];
```

And we have more and more problems:

- There is no such thing is `C` as reading a number and declaring an array with the size of this number. There is a thing called `VLA` treated as extension by some compilers, and even if now, after decades using `C`, it goes into the standard it is still problematic. Do the simple:

  - estimate a max value like you did on the `node` with the 10 ingredients with 64 bytes name
  - or allocate it as needed. `C` was written for this tasks.
- it is almost clear that `sum` is the number of ingredients. It is not event a sum: it is a simple counter. Every recipe has up to 10 ingredients.

  - sum must be there, inside `node`.
- `ingredient` is a vector of strings. Since the 70's we know that `main` prototype can be

```
          int main( int argc, char** argv )
```

And for `main`the command line arguments are... a vector of `getc` strings. Just like `char ingredient [10][64]`should be a vector with `sum` ingredients. It should raise some flags since all `C` program works very well with this arguments for `main`

- `scanf` is a scanner, as the name suggests. And it was written to consume tabular data, like large tables with thousands of lines of similar data. It was not written to get user input. For this we have `fgetc` and `fgets` for example. If we choose `scanf` to read free-form input like from the keyboard we can expect much more work.
- as a scanner, to read nothing is ok to `scanf` so it returns an `int` with the total fields parsed from input. It is very naive not to test. If the user types a `w` instead of a `2` there goes your program to space.
- use symbolic constants like `#define` and avoid magic numbers (like `10` or `64` in your code).
- use pointers and `malloc` and `free` instead of static things.

So a possible way to go

```
typedef struct
{
    char name[64];
    unsigned size;
    unsigned limit;
    char ingredient[10][64];
} Recipe;

typedef struct
{
    unsigned size;
    unsigned limit;
    Recipe   rcp[40];
} Recipes;
```

Now we have **encapsulation**: we can operate on `Recipes`. And it is the data after all. We wrote no line of code yet, but we can see it is easier. Or not?

- `limit` is here so make it easy to avoid overflow on the array.
- `size` is the obvious total of ingredients in each recipe.
- `unsigned` is here so we do not need to worry if someone enter -20 as the `num`
- `Recipes` is a container for the `node`. And it is way better than a modest `node[]` because we can have *metadata*, things like limit and size, kept **inside** the `struct`
- we can even write

```
typedef struct
{
    unsigned size;
    unsigned limit;
    Recipes  coll[40]; // a collection of a collection
} Book;
```

For a book of up to 40 collections of up to 40 recipes each. And we wrote no code yet.

And we can change the code of each one of this things without changing the others.

`Recipe` could be

```
typedef struct
{
    char* name;
    unsigned size;
    unsigned limit;
    char** ingr;
} Recipe;
```

This way each recipe is constructed at run time instead of having a fixed size. And the same principle could be applied to `Recipes` and `Book` for that matter. It is the usual way in `C`.

#### never write interactive code

**This is important:** if you rely on typing recipe's fields each time you **test** your code things can be really hard. For 10 recipes of around 5 ingredients each, and with the program crashing in seconds at each run, life can be sad, i will cost you hours to do simple testing.

- Use files. It is trivial in `C`
- Use factory functions. It is trivial in `C`. It is a function that returns some unique `Recipe` at each call so you can test with 1 or 1,000 recipes at will.

Then when the code is ok you can insert logic to get user input. Only then. And only if it is part of the request: parsing user input is hard and boring.

### write the obvious stuff first

#### display one recipe

It is clear that we need to show a recipe on screen. So let us write this.

From the original code, 5 recipe's prints:

```
cake 4 egg flour sugar butter
omelet 4 egg bacon ham butter
bread 1 flour
breed 0
breag 0
```

Not good. Better plan ahead:

```
    Recipe: cake, 4 ingredients:
        egg
        flour
        sugar 
        butter
--
```

It looks better. And it is better not to code a bunch of `printf` each time we need to print a recipe.

```
int rcp_show(Recipe* rcp, const char* msg)
{
    if (rcp == NULL) return -1;
    if (msg != NULL) printf("%s", msg);
    printf(
        "    Recipe: %s, %u ingredient (s):\n", rcp->name,
        rcp->size);
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < rcp->size; i += 1)
        printf("        %s\n", rcp->ingredient[i]);
    printf("--\n");
    return 0;
};
```

Less than a dozen lines, and it will print as planned. Not good? Change in a single point. Another **OOP** thing, a.k.a. **SRP**, Single Responsibility Principle ;)

Why the second parameter? Well, we are testing and this means we can add a message to each call, embedded in the call itself. Handy. See the example below

#### test ahead

We need a `Recipe`. Any one. From the original code, the first one:

```
cake 4 egg flour sugar butter
```

In `C` terms:

```
    Recipe one = {
        .limit      = 10,
        .size       = 4,
        .name       = "cake",
        .ingredient = {"egg", "flour", "sugar", "butter"}};
```

So this code must run ok:

```
int main(void)
{
    Recipe one = {
        .limit      = 10,
        .size       = 4,
        .name       = "cake",
        .ingredient = {"egg", "flour", "sugar", "butter"}};
    rcp_show(&one, NULL);
    rcp_show(&one, "This is the second);
    rcp_show(&one, "The 3rd one);
    return 0;
}
```

And it shows

```
    Recipe: cake, 4 ingredient (s):
        egg
        flour
        sugar
        butter
--
This is the second    Recipe: cake, 4 ingredient (s):
        egg
        flour
        sugar
        butter
--
The 3rd one    Recipe: cake, 4 ingredient (s):
        egg
        flour
        sugar
        butter
--
```

Good for moral support. And less typing.

#### but we need more `Recipe` and no user input

Time for a factory function: `rcp_factory()`

```
Recipe rcp_factory(unsigned size)
{
    static unsigned usn = 1;
    Recipe          one = {0};
    if (size > 10) size = 10;
    one.limit = 10;
    one.size  = 1 + rand() % size;
    sprintf(one.name, "Recipe #%u", usn);
    usn++;
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < one.size; i += 1)
    {
        unsigned ing = rand() % 100 + 1;  // up to 100
        sprintf(one.ingredient[i], "Ingredient %u", ing);
    }
    return one;
};
```

Not hard: at each call it returns a recipe with controlled random data. The argument limits the total ingredients of each `Recipe`, limited to the obvious 10.

At each call a full struct is copied. In general we would prefer to return a pointer to a new `Recipe` but this is for demonstration only: only static data.

Would it work? How to test? Just change the program above:

```
int main(void)
{
    srand(230922); // to repeat results... 
    Recipe one = {0};
    
    one = rcp_factory(10);
    rcp_show(&one,NULL);

    one = rcp_factory(10);
    rcp_show(&one,NULL);

    one = rcp_factory(10);
    rcp_show(&one,"(last)";
    return 0;
}
```

And it shows

```
    Recipe: Recipe #1, 9 ingredient (s):
        Ingredient 92
        Ingredient 85
        Ingredient 68
        Ingredient 25
        Ingredient 18
        Ingredient 65
        Ingredient 87
        Ingredient 23
        Ingredient 84
--
    Recipe: Recipe #2, 9 ingredient (s):
        Ingredient 93
        Ingredient 7
        Ingredient 17
        Ingredient 15
        Ingredient 54
        Ingredient 64
        Ingredient 81
        Ingredient 95
        Ingredient 24
--
(last)    Recipe: Recipe #3, 5 ingredient (s):
        Ingredient 33
        Ingredient 16
        Ingredient 74
        Ingredient 58
        Ingredient 83
--
```

Good for moral support.

#### but to sort we need a group of `Recipe`

And we already designed one: it is the `Recipes` struct. How to build one?
Keeping the same principle

- write `rcp_g_factory()` and return a group of then.
- write `rcp_sort()` to sort them
- write `rcp_g_show()` since it is obvious that we want to display a collection before and after sort.
- go for a beer.

#### creating the group

It is a matter of copy and paste from `rcp_factory()`. Once again we will use only `static` data. Not smart. All data is being copied around at each call.

```
Recipes rcp_g_factory(unsigned size)
{
    static unsigned usn = 1;
    Recipes          one = {0};
    if (size > 40) size = 40;
    one.limit = 40;
    one.size  = 1 + rand() % size;
    usn++;
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < one.size; i += 1)
        one.rcp[i]   = rcp_factory(10);
    return one;
};
```

Sure, we want to display it.

#### Adding a way to display the collection

Copying and pasting from `rcp_show()` is a good first move since we do not want to waste time

```
int rcp_g_show(Recipes* rcp, const char* msg)
{
    if (rcp == NULL) return -1;
    if (msg != NULL) printf("%s", msg);
    printf("    %u recipe (s) in this group\n\n", rcp->size);
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < rcp->size; i += 1)
        rcp_show(&rcp->rcp[i],NULL);
    printf("End of recipes\n");
    return 0;
};
```

Since we already know how to print one, this is just a matter of calling `rcp_show()`. Thank you **SRP**

Will this work? How to test such a thing?

```
int main(void)
{
    srand(230922);  // to repeat results...
    Recipes grp = rcp_g_factory(15);
    rcp_g_show(&grp, "before sort");
    return 0;
}
```

Not bad huh? Works?

```
before sort    4 recipe (s) in this group

    Recipe: Recipe #1, 2 ingredient (s):
        Ingredient 85
        Ingredient 68
--
    Recipe: Recipe #2, 5 ingredient (s):
        Ingredient 18
        Ingredient 65
        Ingredient 87
        Ingredient 23
        Ingredient 84
--
    Recipe: Recipe #3, 9 ingredient (s):
        Ingredient 93
        Ingredient 7
        Ingredient 17
        Ingredient 15
        Ingredient 54
        Ingredient 64
        Ingredient 81
        Ingredient 95
        Ingredient 24
--
    Recipe: Recipe #4, 5 ingredient (s):
        Ingredient 33
        Ingredient 16
        Ingredient 74
        Ingredient 58
        Ingredient 83
--
End of recipes
```

Good. But no surprise. It is just a loop over things already tested.

#### time to sort `Recipes`

Sure, we want a function like `rcp_g_ sort()` to encapsulate things. We know that we need to sort by some criteria, this criteria is a user-supplied function, so this is the time to pass it down:

```
        int rcp_g_sort( Recipes* group, int (*)(const void*)(const void*))
```

Not much to think: it is the same signature as `qsort`.

#### a problem: recipes are already sorted

Since we are using a *factory function* that returns names as "Recipe #n" they come already sorted. We can just invert the sort order by changing the compare function, but I will change the factory function anyway. **SRP** again.

Just one change: the `sprintf` call from

```
    sprintf(one.name, "Recipe #%u",usn);
```

to

```
    sprintf(
        one.name, "Recipe %c%c%c#%u",
        (1 + rand() % 25 + 'A'), (1 + rand() % 25 + 'A'),
        (1 + rand() % 25 + 'A'), usn);
```

And now the recipes have a 3-letter random prefix to the number.

Will it work?

How to test such a complex thing?

```
int main(void)
{
    srand(230922);  // to repeat results...
    Recipes grp = rcp_g_factory(15);
    rcp_g_show(&grp, "before sort");
    rcp_g_sort(&grp, rcp_compare);
    rcp_g_show(&grp, "\n\nafter sort");
    return 0;
}
```

And it shows

```
before sort    4 recipe (s) in this group

    Recipe: Recipe XKZ#1, 2 ingredient (s):
        Ingredient 18
        Ingredient 65
--
    Recipe: Recipe JOF#2, 7 ingredient (s):
        Ingredient 93
        Ingredient 7
        Ingredient 17
        Ingredient 15
        Ingredient 54
        Ingredient 64
        Ingredient 81
--
    Recipe: Recipe JLC#3, 5 ingredient (s):
        Ingredient 16
        Ingredient 74
        Ingredient 58
        Ingredient 83
        Ingredient 99
--
    Recipe: Recipe HWE#4, 5 ingredient (s):
        Ingredient 53
        Ingredient 48
        Ingredient 46
        Ingredient 68
        Ingredient 74
--
End of recipes


after sort    4 recipe (s) in this group

    Recipe: Recipe HWE#4, 5 ingredient (s):
        Ingredient 53
        Ingredient 48
        Ingredient 46
        Ingredient 68
        Ingredient 74
--
    Recipe: Recipe JLC#3, 5 ingredient (s):
        Ingredient 16
        Ingredient 74
        Ingredient 58
        Ingredient 83
        Ingredient 99
--
    Recipe: Recipe JOF#2, 7 ingredient (s):
        Ingredient 93
        Ingredient 7
        Ingredient 17
        Ingredient 15
        Ingredient 54
        Ingredient 64
        Ingredient 81
--
    Recipe: Recipe XKZ#1, 2 ingredient (s):
        Ingredient 18
        Ingredient 65
--
End of recipes
```

And it works. At first run. Good for moral support

#### what if we want to sort the ingredients by name?

It is the same stuff. The compare function is the same, the data is already a string --- the beauty of student code: little or no testing at all. So it is just a matter of calling `qsort`. Sure it is naive to call `qsort` to sort such a small thing, but it is just a toy.

```
int rcp_sort(
    Recipe* rcb, int (*f)(const void*, const void*))
{
    if (f == NULL) return -1;
    if (rcb == NULL) return -2;
    if (rcb->size == 0) return 0;
    qsort(
        rcb->ingredient, rcb->size,
        sizeof(rcb->ingredient[0]), f);
    return 0;
};
```

It is just a matter of calling `qsort()`

#### how to test `rcp_sort()`

The same thing: let us use

```
int main(void)
{
    srand(230922);  // to repeat results...
    Recipe rcp = rcp_factory(10);
    rcp_show(&rcp, "[before sorting by ingredient]");
    rcp_sort(&rcp, rcp_compare);
    rcp_show(&rcp, "[after sorting by ingredient]");
    return 0;
}
```

That shows

```
[before sorting by ingredient]    Recipe: Recipe SKR01, 9 ingredient (s):
        Ingredient MPS25
        Ingredient SOJ23
        Ingredient EPR07
        Ingredient YUG64
        Ingredient YQI45
        Ingredient UYI58
        Ingredient DZP40
        Ingredient YSV48
        Ingredient ZWU93
--
[after sorting by ingredient]    Recipe: Recipe SKR01, 9 ingredient (s):
        Ingredient DZP40
        Ingredient EPR07
        Ingredient MPS25
        Ingredient SOJ23
        Ingredient UYI58
        Ingredient YQI45
        Ingredient YSV48
        Ingredient YUG64
        Ingredient ZWU93
--
```

It is time for me to stop.

Here is the final code. A few changes: I changed all *factory functions* to use the 3-letters prefix in the names, to better show the sorting process.

### The complete code at this point

#### source

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#define MAX_COLL_SIZE 20
#define MAX_INGR_COUNT 10

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct
{
    char     name[64];
    unsigned size;
    unsigned limit;
    char     ingredient[MAX_INGR_COUNT][64];
} Recipe;

typedef struct
{
    unsigned size;
    unsigned limit;
    Recipe   rcp[MAX_COLL_SIZE];
} Recipes;

typedef struct
{
    unsigned size;
    unsigned limit;
    Recipes  coll[MAX_COLL_SIZE];
} Book;

int    rcp_compare(const void* a, const void* b);
Recipe rcp_factory(unsigned);
int    rcp_show(Recipe*, const char*);
int    rcp_sort(Recipe*, int (*)(const void*, const void*));

Recipes rcp_g_factory(unsigned);
int     rcp_g_show(Recipes*, const char*);
int rcp_g_sort(Recipes*, int (*)(const void*, const void*));

int main(void)
{
    srand(230922);  // to repeat results...
    Recipes grp = rcp_g_factory(15);
    rcp_g_show(&grp, "before sort");
    rcp_g_sort(&grp, rcp_compare);
    rcp_g_show(&grp, "\n\nafter sort");

    Recipe rcp = rcp_factory(10);
    rcp_show(&rcp, "\n\n\n[before sorting by ingredient]");
    rcp_sort(&rcp, rcp_compare);
    rcp_show(&rcp, "[after sorting by ingredient]");
    return 0;
}

int rcp_compare(const void* a, const void* b)
{
    Recipe* A = (Recipe*)a;
    Recipe* B = (Recipe*)b;
    return strcmp(A->name, B->name);
};

Recipe rcp_factory(unsigned size)
{
    static unsigned usn = 1;
    Recipe          one = {0};
    if (size > MAX_INGR_COUNT) size = MAX_INGR_COUNT;
    one.limit = size;
    one.size  = 1 + rand() % size;
    sprintf(
        one.name, "Recipe %c%c%c%02u",
        (1 + rand() % 25 + 'A'), (1 + rand() % 25 + 'A'),
        (1 + rand() % 25 + 'A'), usn);
    usn++;
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < one.size; i += 1)
    {
        unsigned ing = rand() % 100 + 1;  // up to 100
        sprintf(
            one.ingredient[i], "Ingredient %c%c%c%02u",
            (1 + rand() % 25 + 'A'),
            (1 + rand() % 25 + 'A'),
            (1 + rand() % 25 + 'A'), ing);
    }
    return one;
};

Recipes rcp_g_factory(unsigned size)
{
    static unsigned usn = 1;
    Recipes         one = {0};
    if (size > MAX_COLL_SIZE) size = MAX_COLL_SIZE;
    one.limit = size;
    one.size  = 1 + rand() % size;
    usn++;
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < one.size; i += 1)
        one.rcp[i] = rcp_factory(10);
    return one;
};

int rcp_show(Recipe* rcp, const char* msg)
{
    if (rcp == NULL) return -1;
    if (msg != NULL) printf("%s", msg);
    printf(
        "    Recipe: %s, %u ingredient (s):\n", rcp->name,
        rcp->size);
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < rcp->size; i += 1)
        printf("        %s\n", rcp->ingredient[i]);
    printf("--\n");
    return 0;
}

int rcp_sort(
    Recipe* rcb, int (*f)(const void*, const void*))
{
    if (f == NULL) return -1;
    if (rcb == NULL) return -2;
    if (rcb->size == 0) return 0;
    qsort(
        rcb->ingredient, rcb->size,
        sizeof(rcb->ingredient[0]), f);
    return 0;
};

int rcp_g_show(Recipes* rcp, const char* msg)
{
    if (rcp == NULL) return -1;
    if (msg != NULL) printf("%s", msg);
    printf(
        "    %u recipe (s) in this group\n\n", rcp->size);
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < rcp->size; i += 1)
        rcp_show(&rcp->rcp[i], NULL);
    printf("End of recipes\n");
    return 0;
}
int rcp_g_sort(
    Recipes* coll, int (*f)(const void*, const void*))
{
    if (coll == NULL) return -1;
    if (f == NULL) return -2;
    qsort(coll->rcp, coll->size, sizeof(Recipe), f);

    return 0;
};

// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77161477/
// qsort-in-struct-but-the-sorted-struct-is-messy
```

#### output

```
before sort    4 recipe (s) in this group

    Recipe: Recipe ZSK01, 2 ingredient (s):
        Ingredient XMP18
        Ingredient HSO84
--
    Recipe: Recipe OEP02, 7 ingredient (s):
        Ingredient UYU81
        Ingredient IYQ33
        Ingredient PUY83
        Ingredient XDZ90
        Ingredient SYS46
        Ingredient SZW70
        Ingredient NOJ53
--
    Recipe: Recipe URV03, 7 ingredient (s):
        Ingredient ZSY98
        Ingredient FPD57
        Ingredient YWS83
        Ingredient BQJ19
        Ingredient SUP23
        Ingredient ECD99
        Ingredient ZXS03
--
    Recipe: Recipe JGZ04, 7 ingredient (s):
        Ingredient NLM42
        Ingredient MKQ13
        Ingredient UYF73
        Ingredient LWE47
        Ingredient DID71
        Ingredient FFF20
        Ingredient IYJ51
--
End of recipes


after sort    4 recipe (s) in this group

    Recipe: Recipe JGZ04, 7 ingredient (s):
        Ingredient NLM42
        Ingredient MKQ13
        Ingredient UYF73
        Ingredient LWE47
        Ingredient DID71
        Ingredient FFF20
        Ingredient IYJ51
--
    Recipe: Recipe OEP02, 7 ingredient (s):
        Ingredient UYU81
        Ingredient IYQ33
        Ingredient PUY83
        Ingredient XDZ90
        Ingredient SYS46
        Ingredient SZW70
        Ingredient NOJ53
--
    Recipe: Recipe URV03, 7 ingredient (s):
        Ingredient ZSY98
        Ingredient FPD57
        Ingredient YWS83
        Ingredient BQJ19
        Ingredient SUP23
        Ingredient ECD99
        Ingredient ZXS03
--
    Recipe: Recipe ZSK01, 2 ingredient (s):
        Ingredient XMP18
        Ingredient HSO84
--
End of recipes



[before sorting by ingredient]    Recipe: Recipe KDF05, 5 ingredient (s):
        Ingredient GYM89
        Ingredient YNR73
        Ingredient OVJ84
        Ingredient ZNK30
        Ingredient NNT31
--
[after sorting by ingredient]    Recipe: Recipe KDF05, 5 ingredient (s):
        Ingredient GYM89
        Ingredient NNT31
        Ingredient OVJ84
        Ingredient YNR73
        Ingredient ZNK30
--
```

I did almost no testing.

Comment: `(1 + rand() % 25 + 'A')` ... You don't seem to have a solid grasp of the subject...

Comment: @Fe2O3 That is because I have not! Anyone can answer and ask at Stack Overflow!

Comment: This answer disregards the OP's question, then goes off in some verbose and bizarre tangent for some unknown reason. While "_anyone can answer_", you have not answered the question posed. You disregard/dismiss the OP's data source to, it seems to me, stoke your ego publishing amateur code involving "factories". Bad answer.

Comment: "_Sure it is naive to call qsort to sort such a small thing, but it is just a toy._" Your function `rcp_compare()` casts the two void pointers to `Recipe*`, then dereferences a member of that structure... When `Recipe` is changed and `name` is no longer the first member, what you've written to sort ingredients will either yield garbage or cause a mysterious crash for hours of happy debugging inquiry... This is a bad answer...

Comment: @Fe203, about `qsort`, I do not know your level experience on this _callback_ thing, but you may have documentation: the compare function is user-provided. If the data to sort on is changed it is the user's task to provided a new one. See as no surprise if `qsort` fails if the user changes the data and not the compare function.

Comment: @Fe203, maybe you have a book on _design patterns_ and could read about the factory pattern. I do not know your level of experience on this but note that the _factories_ in the example are in fact functions that returns a complete _object_. And consider that in `C` a function like this could even get an `uuid` thing and reply with a `void*` of data corresponding to a predefined object, sort of a polymorphic object factory. It is the factory design pattern...

Comment: @Fe203, as for _disregard/dismiss the OP's data source_ it is a strange comment. Maybe you _disregarded_ the OP code in full: the OP's data source is the user. Data is read by `scanf` calls into a `VLA`. And there is no data object. I even used a `Recipe` thing in example to keep it as related as possible. I believe you _disregard/dismiss_ the part on this answer when I write about interactive code and about encapsulation.

Answer (score 3):

The code sorts the array of recipes, but each recipe becomes separated from its `sum`.

Here's the changes required:

```
typedef struct node{
    char name[64];
    int sum; // <== here!!
    char ingredient[10][64];
}node;

int main(){
    int num; scanf("%d", &num);
    node recipe[num];
    //input
    for(int i = 0; i < num; i++){
        printf( "Recipe #%d:\n", i + 1 ); // alert user to start of next recipe
        scanf("%s", recipe[i].name);
        scanf("%d", &recipe[i].sum); // <== here!!
        for(int j = 0; j < 10 && j < recipe[i]sum; j++){ // <==here!!
            scanf("%s", recipe[i].ingredient[j]);
        }
    }
    //sort
    qsort(recipe, num, sizeof(node), compare);

    //print out to check
    printf("\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < num; i++){
        printf("%s ", recipe[i].name);
        for(int j = 0; j < recipe[i].sum; j++){ // <== finally here
            printf("%s ", recipe[i].ingredient[j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Yes, I used a "magic number" with `10` appearing in the code. In the future, it would be better to use `#define MAX_INGRED 10` (or some such value) and use that token instead.

---

"*I also want to sort the ingredient within each node*"

Good attempt, but this might work better

```
for( int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    qsort(
        recipe[i].ingredient,
        recipe[i].sum, // the correct # for each different recipe
        sizeof(recipe[0].ingredient[0]),
        mycompare
    );
```

Comment: One more point to note: Although it's convenient and proven to work, `qsort()` is not the best choice to sort small quantities. In this case it doesn't matter, but it's something to keep in the back of your mind for when you sort 1million arrays each made up of only 4 or 5 elements...

Answer (score 1):

Key Problem:

**Unsorted `sum[]`**

Code is only sorting `recipe[]`, but not also `sum[]`.

Move `sum` into a member of `node`.

---

Other Problems:

**Missing headers**

Prepend

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
```

**`scanf()` woes**

- `scanf("%s"...` risk buffer overrun without a *width*.
- Better code would check the return values.

Comment: Thanks, I always forget to check the return value...